# PHP scandir(): How do I prevent echoing '.' and '..' directories?

Tags: php, scandir

Having some issues regarding the `scandir()` function in PHP.

When trying to echo a list of files in the current directory, it echoes `.` and `..` as directories. I've attempted to filter these out like so:

```
<?php

$dir = "pages";
if ($d = scandir($dir)) {
    foreach ($d as $value) {
        echo("<script>console.log(\"$value\")</script>");
        if ($value !== '.' || $value !== '..') {
            echo("<p><a href=\"$dir/$value\">$value</a></p>");
        } else {
            echo("");
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like it's something obvious that I'm missing.

Has anyone got any ideas?

-R

Comment: It's in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#107215

Comment: For two `!=(=)` you have to use `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: No you can use both && and ||. Just depends if you want an and or a or condition

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), `scandir()` returns an array of files and directories from the target directory. So you could use `array_diff`, which in the end would return an array containing all the entries from the first array that are not present in the second array:

```
array_diff(scandir($directory), ['..', '.']);
```

Or if you're too lazy for that, you could actually `array_shift` the first two elements:

```
$dir = "pages";
if($d = scandir($dir)) {
    array_shift($d);
    array_shift($d);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would be a simple solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

I like doing this:

```
   $dir = "pages";
   if($d = scandir($dir)) {
        foreach($d as $file){
            if(substr($file,0,1) == '.') continue;

            echo "$file\n";
        }
   }
```

This way it skips all `$file` starting with `.` such as `.htaccess` etc.

But I have a lot of stuff like this in my projects:

```
 .
 ..
 .buildpath
 .git
 .gitignore
 .htaccess
 .project
 .settings
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution, you could also write it like: `$file[0] == '.'`

Answer (score 0):

I would use is_file(). It will also avoid directories.

```
$dir = "pages";
if ($d = scandir($dir)) {
    foreach ($d as $value) {
        echo("<script>console.log(\"$value\")</script>");
        if (is_file($value)) {
            echo("<p><a href=\"$dir/$value\">$value</a></p>");
        } else {
            echo("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like a flawless solution, however, I was ideally planning to build a mini file system on my raspberry pi just to have a local cloud, essentially. So it would definitely require the listing of directories. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Just continue your loop when your find `.` or `..`

Simply add this in first line of `foreach` block:

```
if($value == '.' || $value == '..') continue;
# your rest of codes
```

OR

```
if(in_array($value, array(".",".."))) continue;
# your rest of codes
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code:

```
if ($value !== '.' || $value !== '..') {
```

when $value equals "." then it certainly doesn't equal ".." at the same time, so one side of the "||" will be true for ".", the other for ".." and the overall result will be true.

you need either:

```
if ($value !== '.' && $value !== '..') {
```

or

```
if ($value == '.' || $value == '..') continue;
```

Comment: I had previously tried this, but to no success unfortunately. I also haven't looked at my own question in a few days, since I've been busy. I'll have a crack at a couple of these solutions whenever I can.
Thanks for the response though!